# Plotting a timeseries in R as stacked bar

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

I have a dataset that look like the following

```
| SUBJECT | ACTION | DURATION |
|---------|--------|----------|
| 1       | A      | 39,57    |
| 1       | B      | 1,48     |
| 1       | B      | 53,22    |
| 1       | A      | 10,42    |
| 1       | C      | 8,33     |
| 1       | D      | 1,00     |
| 1       | E      | 7,50     |
| 1       | D      | 0,35     |
| 2       | D      | 1,35     |
| 2       | B      | 2,60     |
| 2       | C      | 1,47     |
| 2       | D      | 1,13     |
| 2       | A      | 4,23     |
| 2       | A      | 1,62     |
| 2       | A      | 7,58     |
| 2       | C      | 133,47   |
| 2       | D      | 14,82    |
| 3       | D      | 0,45     |
| 3       | D      | 1,07     |
| 3       | A      | 61,62    |
| 3       | D      | 42,45    |
| 3       | D      | 4,47     |
| 3       | B      | 100,92   |
| 3       | E      | 9,05     |
| 3       | C      | 9,55     |
```

Which represents 3 subjects performing actions (starting at the same time) for a certain duration. Example, subject 1 performed action A for 39.57 minutes, then action B for 1.48 minutes, then action B again for 53.22 minutes (it is important to differentiate subsequent actions although of the same category).

I would like to plot such data as in the image below 
[image]

Where each horizontal bar represents all the action of a certain subject, the length of component of the bar represents the duration and its colour represents the type of action (A, B, C, etc).

Any help with this? Thanks

Comment: You mentioned "length of component of the bar represents the duration" but you want time on x axis too.. how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(SUBJECT, DURATION, fill = ACTION)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Here is the data frame used (to make it reproducible).  Next time please use `dput` to output the data in the question.

```
DF <- 
structure(list(SUBJECT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), ACTION = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), DURATION = c(39.57, 1.48, 
53.22, 10.42, 8.33, 1, 7.5, 0.35, 1.35, 2.6, 1.47, 1.13, 4.23, 
1.62, 7.58, 133.47, 14.82, 0.45, 1.07, 61.62, 42.45, 4.47, 100.92, 
9.05, 9.55)), .Names = c("SUBJECT", "ACTION", "DURATION"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```